# && y || no funcionan

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando hacer un tres en raya en java script ( en vez de círculos y x he usado x e y), y a la hora de verificar si hay alguna línea que tenga 3 y o 3 x seguidas me pone que x e y han ganado, y eso que para probarlo he puesto todo x menos 1 que era y.

Gracias de antemano.

Por cierto todas esas variables que hay al principio representa cada lugar del "tablero". (Por ejemplo AI es arriba izquierda)

```
var AM = "x"
var AD = "y"

var MI = "x"
var MM = "x"
var MD = "x"

var AbI = "x"
var AbM = "x"
var AbD = "x"

document.write(AI + AM + AD + "<br>" + MI + MM + MD + "<br>" + AbI + AbM + AbD)


if( (MI && MM && MD) || (AI && AM && AD) || (AbI && AbD && AbM) || (AI && MI && AbI) || (AM && MM && AbM) || (AD && MD && AbD) || (AI && MM && AbD) || (AD && MM && AbI) == "x"){
    alert("gana x")
}
if((MI && MM && MD) || (AI && AM && AD) == "y"){
    alert("gana y")
}
```

Comment: Y cuál es el problema?

Comment: esto es un abuso de logica jajaja, creo que el problema esta en en que no consideras que Cada una de las variables son verdaderas siempre y que al compararlas con "x" (solo la ultima porque no cerraste el el() ) siempre sera verdadera

Comment: y como lo resuelvo, no entiendo

Answer (score 3):

Ese uso de los operadores lógicos no es adecuado (MI && MM && MD) dan como resultado el último valor. Es decir tienes mal puestas las comparaciones. Fíjate

```
 (AI && AM && AD) // te da 'y'
 (AD && AM && AI) // te da 'x',
```

Como ves cambiando los operandos cambia el resultado. La forma correcta es hacer las comparaciones uno por uno:

```
 (AI == "y" && AM == "y" && AD == "y")
 (AI == "x" && AM == "x" && AD == "x")
```

O también puedes hacerlo de otra manera en este caso, aclarando bastante el código
En lugar de

```
(AI == "y" && AM == "y" && AD == "y")
```

Pues construir una cadena y comparar la cadena. Esta línea te compara si la fila superior son todas 'x'

```
(AI+AM+AD == "xxx")
```

Y bueno, si comparas las x y el resultado es que ganan las 'x' no tienes que comparar las 'y'. Si no gana la x compruebas la y y si no gana la y tampoco, no hay ganador. El algoritmo es algo así.

```
if(condiciones de x en linea)
     gana x
else
     if(condiciones de y en linea)
          gana y
     else
          no gana nadie
```

Comment: Muchas gracias (:

Comment: @Jesús recuerda marcar esta respuesta como la correcta, para cerrar el tema.

Answer (score 0):

Unas consideraciones: si hacemos `if ( variable )`, el bloque se evalua como `false` si `variable` asume alguno de los siguientes valores:

- `false`
- 0
- `undefined`
- `null`
- `NaN`
- `""`

En todos los demás casos es `true`.

Entonces `if( (MI && MM && MD)`  va a dar `true` siempre que ninguno de los valores de `MI`,`MM` o `MD` sea alguno de los mencionados. Solo con que sean strings no vacíos ya va a ser `true`.

Comment: Lo que mencionas tiene que ver con los valores *falsy* y *truthy* de los tipos de dato